# Anonymous Class - Can we have two new objects for a same anonymous class?

Tags: java, class, object, reference, anonymous-inner-class

When we create an anonymous class, like

```
Employee emp = new Employee() {
  void get() {
    //Some body
  }
  void put() {    
    //Some body
  }
};
emp.set();
emp.get();
```

the object reference emp refers to the object of the above anonymous inner class.
We can also create another anonymous class whose object can be referred by the same object reference, like

```
emp = new Employee() {
      void x() {
        //Some body
      }
      void y() {    
        //Some body
      }
    };
    emp.x();
    emp.y();
```

But is there any way of creating another object for the same anonymous class? Is it possible to create a new object for an existing anonymous class, if needed?

Comment: Why would you want to? Make it a named class.

Comment: Of course it's simple. But when I just need the class for a short operation and require two objects, it might require.

Comment: I'm wondering if it is possible in java or in any other language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb - if you want more than one instance of the same anonymous class, chances are it shouldn't be anonymous - just make it a plain old named class and instantiate as many objects of it as you want.

One dirty trick you could use, though, is accessing the instance's `getClass()` and using reflection to instantiate a new instance:

```
Employee emp2 = emp.getClass().newInstance();
```

Comment: That is absolutely working. I'm looking for something like this. Thank you!